# Apply Watson's lemma to Gamma function

Tags: numerical-methods

I was wondering is there anyone know how to show that the gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ satisfies the conditions of Watson's Lemma, where z is on the right half plane. After I changed variable t=xv
$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{z}dt=z^{z}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-z(v-\log{v})}dv$$

Comment: and those conditions are...

Comment: I believe you need a more general method, like [Laplace's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).

Comment: Well, in complex plane, Laplace's method does not work. Even if it works, it won't generate complete asymptotic series.

Comment: conditions are when you generate the standard form that can apply Watson's lemma, $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zt}f(t)dt$ you have to show f(t) is analytic from 0 to infinity, and f(t) is bounded by $Ke^{bt}$, where K,b are some positive constants.